# Android: Mediaplayer works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: java, android, audio

My Games music plays in the Emulated Phone but not on my actual device (galaxy S7).

```
myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.medieval_loop);
myMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);
myMediaPlayer.setVolume(volume,volume);
myMediaPlayer.start();
audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build();
```

Anyone had to deal with this before?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the solution was to change my audioattributes to

```
audioAttributes2 = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();
```